# Making where clause dynamic in sql in CI

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, codeigniter

I want to display the content of page dynamically this following code is working fine but it only shows the content of specific id...how can i make that dynamic??

Model

```
public function getAllDepartment() {
$join = $this->db->query( "Select * from labreport_db inner join patient_db on labreport_db.P_ID=patient_db.id  where labreport_db.P_ID=15");
return $join->result_array();

    }
```

Controller

```
public function reportDisplay(){

 $data['clubs'] = $this->labdoc_model->getAllDepartment();
 $this->load->view('SystemAdminUser/labreport', $data);
    }
```

Comment: pass P_ID=15 in getAllDepartment($P_ID); and receive in model as variable and put that variable in query as dynamic

Comment: I dont want to pass 15 thats for demo only. That changes dynamically. this is what i want to kno.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of ways doing it. One of them is through CI routing ability.

**Model**

```
public function getAllDepartment($p_id = 0) {
    $join = $this->db->query( "Select * from labreport_db inner join patient_db on labreport_db.P_ID=patient_db.id  where labreport_db.P_ID={$p_id}");
    return $join->result_array();
}
```

Comment: I added `$p_id` as a variable to fetch the ID dynamically.

**Controller**

```
public function reportDisplay($p_id = 0){
    $data['clubs'] = $this->labdoc_model->getAllDepartment($p_id);
    $this->load->view('SystemAdminUser/labreport', $data);
}
```

Comment: We also add a variable called `$p_id` in the `reportDisplay` function and pass it to your model's `getAllDepartment()`function.

**How to fetch the report dynamically**

I don't know your URL structure, but for example purposes let's say it's http://localhost/yourcontrollername/reportDisplay/

To access it dynamically, simply add an ID after the `reportDisplay`

For example:

- http://localhost/yourcontrollername/reportDisplay/15
- http://localhost/yourcontrollername/reportDisplay/10

Answer (score 1):

Hold the id in some variable like:

```
$pid = $_REQUEST['p_id'];   
// $_REQUEST['p_id'] will contain the dynamic value in it
```

and put this variable in your query like:

```
where labreport_db.P_ID = $pid;
```

It will show the data for the value contained in $pid, and make sure it contains the dynamic value in it.

Comment: I want that value to be dynamic. There can be any other value instead of 15.

Answer (score 1):

There is simple work around for this using Query Builder class of CI.

So this is how your code will look like,

```
$id=15;
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('labreport_db');
$this->db->join('patient_db', 'labreport_db.P_ID = patient_db.id');
$this->db->where('labreport_db.P_ID', $id);
$query = $this->db->get();
```

This is standard approach in CI to make database operation using query builder class in which you can perform dynamic `WHERE` condition.

For which just change the value of `$id` and the query will do the needful.

Reference: https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#selecting-data

Answer (score 1):

You can used this code for you solution.

**Model.php**

```
public function getAllDepartment($pId) {
    $join = $this->db->query( "Select * from labreport_db inner join     patient_db on labreport_db.P_ID=patient_db.id  where   labreport_db.P_ID=".$pId);
    return $join->result_array();
}
```

**Controller.php**

```
public function reportDisplay(){
     $pid = $_REQUEST['pid']; //OR  $_GET['pid']; OR  $_POST['pid']; You can pass your id for get content
     $data['clubs'] = $this->labdoc_model->getAllDepartment($pid);
     $this->load->view('SystemAdminUser/labreport', $data);
}
```

Comment: This is same... it will show the content with id 15. which i don't want. That 15 should be dynamic which changes .

Comment: you can pass id from you contorller and you can get output. reportDisplay action get via `POST and GET` Request pass id in function `getAllDepartment`